# Which network topology does Windows 'hostednetwork' use? Is it equivalent to Ad-Hoc's topology?

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless, netsh, topology

I set up an Access Point using the following command:

### `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=DotA key=pass keyUsage=persistent`

I am eager to know what topology (star, mesh etc.) does it use, so I may use it optimally as per my needs.

P.S.: I did [post](https://superuser.com/questions/622763/which-network-topology-does-windows-hostednetwork-use-is-it-equivalent-to-ad) my question on SuperUser.com but got no response.
Hoping to be lucky here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that

> The wireless Hosted Network is a new WLAN feature supported on Windows 7 and on Windows Server 2008 R2 with the Wireless LAN Service installed. This feature implements two major functions:
>
> - The virtualization of a physical wireless adapter into more than one virtual wireless adapter sometimes referred to as Virtual Wi-Fi.
> - software-based wireless access point (AP) sometimes referred to as a SoftAP that uses a designated virtual wireless adapter.

and

> With this feature, a Windows computer can use a single physical wireless adapter to connect as a client to a hardware access point (AP), while at the same time acting as a software AP allowing other wireless-capable devices to connect to it.

As it is on the AP mode (or managed mode) when you want to connect other wireless device to be connected to your laptop as a client (phone, laptop, tablet, etc.) so that it would be a star topology.

But when it connects to an Access Point like a WiFi router, then it will act as a client (or station adapter), then it would be a start topology again.

`Mesh` topology are commonly used on `ad-hoc` wlan mode.